# Multiple select2 input's value getting using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have some input fields with same class with select2,

After selecting type and garage, When I click on stock field, then previously selected value will be put on the clicked stock, But my code gives me the same as first and second times,

My Code in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kabircse/5fh5jmxu/

Could you help me?

Html Code:

```
   <div id="items">
    <p>Type:</p>
    <select name="Type[]" class="select2 pd" style="width: 50%;">
    <option value="1">Garage1</option>
    <option value="2">Garage2</option>
    <option value="3">Garage3</option>
    <option value="4">Street parking4</option>
    <option value="5">Carport5</option>
     </select>
    <input type="hidden">  

    <p>Garage:</p>
    <select name="garage[]" class="select2 gd" style="width: 50%;">
    <option value="1">Garage1</option>
    <option value="2">Garage2</option>
    <option value="3">Garage3</option>
    <option value="4">Street parking4</option>
    <option value="5">Carport5</option>
    </select>
    <p>Stock:</p><input type="text" name="stock[]" class="stock">

    <p>Type:</p>
    <select name="Type[]" class="select2 pd" style="width: 50%;">
    <option value="1">Garage1</option>
    <option value="2">Garage2</option>
    <option value="3">Garage3</option>
    <option value="4">Street parking4</option>
    <option value="5">Carport5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden">  

   <p>Garage:</p>
    <select name="garage[]" class="select2 gd" style="width: 50%;">
    <option value="1">Garage1</option>
    <option value="2">Garage2</option>
    <option value="3">Garage3</option>
    <option value="4">Street parking4</option>
    <option value="5">Carport5</option>
   </select>
    <p>Stock:</p><input type="text" name="stock[]" class="stock">

          <p>Type:</p>
    <select name="Type[]" class="select2 pd" style="width: 50%;">
    <option value="1">Garage1</option>
    <option value="2">Garage2</option>
    <option value="3">Garage3</option>
    <option value="4">Street parking4</option>
    <option value="5">Carport5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden">  

   <p>Garage:</p>
    <select name="garage[]" class="select2 gd" style="width: 50%;">
    <option value="1">Garage1</option>
    <option value="2">Garage2</option>
    <option value="3">Garage3</option>
    <option value="4">Street parking4</option>
    <option value="5">Carport5</option>
    </select>
    <p>Stock:</p><input type="text" name="stock[]" class="stock">

    <p>Type:</p>
    <select name="Type2[]" class="select2 pd2" style="width: 50%;">
    <option value="1">Garage1</option>
    <option value="2">Garage2</option>
    <option value="3">Garage3</option>
    <option value="4">Street parking4</option>
    <option value="5">Carport5</option>
    </select>  
    <input type="hidden">  

    <p>Garage:</p>
    <select name="garage2[]" class="select2 gd2" style="width: 50%;">
    <option value="1">Garage1</option>
    <option value="2">Garage2</option>
    <option value="3">Garage3</option>
    <option value="4">Street parking4</option>
    <option value="5">Carport5</option>
    </select> 
    Stock<input type="text" name="stock2[]" class="stock2">
    </div>
```

JS:

```
  $(".select2").select2();
$('#items').on('click','.stock',function(){
            var indx = $('.stock').index(this);
            var p_id = $('.pd').eq(indx).select2("val");
            var g_id = $('.gd').eq(indx).select2("val");
            v = p_id+g_id;
              $('.stock').eq(indx).val(v);  
        });
```

Comment: one error is there se no select box is properly closed

Comment: I have fixed this but same problem. Could you try my jsfiddle ?

Comment: can you change this into table format?

Comment: table format ? Is their any benefit converting it into table ?

Comment: take my answer below, it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please fine the below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../repo/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="../repo/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../repo/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Type</td>
      <td>Garage</td>
      <td>Stock</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><select name="Type[]" class="select2 pd" style="width: 50%;">
          <option value="1">Garage1</option>
          <option value="2">Garage2</option>
          <option value="3">Garage3</option>
          <option value="4">Street parking4</option>
          <option value="5">Carport5</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden">
      </td>
      <td><select name="garage[]" class="select2 gd" style="width: 50%;">
          <option value="1">Garage1</option>
          <option value="2">Garage2</option>
          <option value="3">Garage3</option>
          <option value="4">Street parking4</option>
          <option value="5">Carport5</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="stock[]" class="stock">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><select name="Type[]" class="select2 pd" style="width: 50%;">
          <option value="1">Garage1</option>
          <option value="2">Garage2</option>
          <option value="3">Garage3</option>
          <option value="4">Street parking4</option>
          <option value="5">Carport5</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden">
      </td>
      <td><select name="garage[]" class="select2 gd" style="width: 50%;">
          <option value="1">Garage1</option>
          <option value="2">Garage2</option>
          <option value="3">Garage3</option>
          <option value="4">Street parking4</option>
          <option value="5">Carport5</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="stock[]" class="stock">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><select name="Type[]" class="select2 pd" style="width: 50%;">
          <option value="1">Garage1</option>
          <option value="2">Garage2</option>
          <option value="3">Garage3</option>
          <option value="4">Street parking4</option>
          <option value="5">Carport5</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden">
      </td>
      <td><select name="garage[]" class="select2 gd" style="width: 50%;">
          <option value="1">Garage1</option>
          <option value="2">Garage2</option>
          <option value="3">Garage3</option>
          <option value="4">Street parking4</option>
          <option value="5">Carport5</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="stock[]" class="stock">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" name="add" value="Add More" id="addMore" />
<script>
    $('table').on('click', '.stock', function(event){
        var parentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var type = $(parentTr).find('td:eq(0) select').val();
        var garage = $(parentTr).find('td:eq(1) select').val();

        var total = parseInt(type)+parseInt(garage);
        $(this).val(total);
    });

    $('#addMore').click(function(){
        var newElement = '<tr><td><select name="Type[]" class="select2 pd" style="width: 50%;"><option value="1">Garage1</option><option value="2">Garage2</option><option value="3">Garage3</option><option value="4">Street parking4</option><option value="5">Carport5</option></select><input type="hidden"></td><td><select name="garage[]" class="select2 gd" style="width: 50%;"><option value="1">Garage1</option><option value="2">Garage2</option><option value="3">Garage3</option><option value="4">Street parking4</option><option value="5">Carport5</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="stock[]" class="stock"></td></tr>';

        $('table tbody').append(newElement)
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You converted this into table, But sir, In my actual code I have to add a row with add more button, that situation your js code will work ?

Comment: OOps !, Sir your input is without select2. But actually I need input with select2.

Comment: Wait I am trying this.

Comment: I added dynamic add row. take my updated code and check

Comment: Nice. Could you explain  

var type = $(parentTr).find('td:eq(0) select').val();
var garage = $(parentTr).find('td:eq(1) select').val();  

Could you explain this two lines how works for overall program ?

Comment: I assigned closest tr to the variable parent tr.. Then each td will be the child.. So zeroth child refers first select. Is it clear?

Comment: Your code works fine. but how it takes the value, I need 15 reputations to upvote.

If I want,  When I select the second input dropdown then it  will sum  the both first and current dropdown value  and put this to current stock field, where I have to change  sir ?

Comment: Instead of clicking on sum text box you have to do it on change in select box

Answer (score 1):

Try  to understand the  basics of

```
     var parentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var type = $(parentTr).find('td:eq(0) select').val();
    var garage = $(parentTr).find('td:eq(1) select').val();
```

closest() travels up the DOM tree, not down, so if $(this) equals the current row, you will never find the td tags inside it using closest('td').

Assuming that you can't simply use the id attribute to access the input directly, as Jamie suggested, you would need to use:

```
$(this).children("td:eq(0)");
```

. . . to get the first td of the row, assuming that $(this) references the row that you want. To access the value of the select inside it, use:

```
$(this).children("td:eq(0)").find("select").val();

$(this).closest("tr").children("td:eq(0)").find("select").val();
```

. . . or . . .

```
 $(this).closest("tr").children("td:eq(0) select").val();
```

(the first one is faster)